# React components not unmounting when they are no longer generated by render()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I change this.state.rows with setState from [a, b, c] to [d, e, f] I get a b c d e f instead of d e f. I can't comprehend how that is possible. I have confirmed with the react dev plugin for firefox that the state is updating correctly and a, b, c is replaced with d, e, f.
Any suggestion on where to begin troubleshooting this would be helpful. I am at a total loss and can't find any documentation anywhere of a bug that causes old results of render to not unmount.

```
getFilter(newFilters){
    let newFilter = Object.assign({}, this.state.filter, newFilters);
    this.setState({filter: newFilter});
}

// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    if(Object.keys(diff(this.props.filter || {}, prevProps.filter || {})).length !== 0){
        this.setState({filter: Object.assign({}, this.state.filter, this.props.filter)});
    }
    else if(Object.keys(diff(this.props.rows || {}, prevProps.rows || {})).length !== 0){  // cleaning incoming rows
        console.log(diff(this.props.rows || {}, prevProps.rows || {}));
        let newState = {};
        newState["header"] = this.props.schema;
        const headerKeys = Object.keys(this.props.schema);
        let rows = [];
        let emptyCounter = {};
        this.props.rows.forEach(row=>{
            if(Object.keys(row).length > 0){
                let cleanRow = [];
                const rowKeys = Object.keys(row);
                headerKeys.forEach(headerKey=>{
                    let value = "";
                    if(rowKeys.includes(headerKey)){
                        value = row[headerKey].value;
                        if(typeof(value) == "string"){
                            value = value.trim();
                        }
                    }
                    if(!value){
                        emptyCounter[headerKey] = ((emptyCounter[headerKey] || 0) + 1);
                    }
                    let newCell = Object.assign({}, this.props.schema[headerKey]);
                    newCell["value"] = value;
                    newCell["key"] = headerKey;
                    cleanRow.push(newCell);
                });
                rows.push(cleanRow);
            }
        });
        Object.keys(emptyCounter).forEach(key=>{
            if(emptyCounter[key] == rows.length){
                rows = rows.map(row=>{
                    let newRow = row.filter(cell=>cell.key !== key);
                    return newRow;
                });
                delete newState["header"][key];
            }
        });
        newState["rows"] = rows;
        this.setState(newState);
    }
    else if(Object.keys(diff(this.state.filter || {}, prevState.filter || {})).length !== 0){
        this.props.updateTable(this.state.filter);
    }
}

getRows(){
    console.log(this.state.rows.length)
    return this.state.rows.map(row=>{
        return <TableRow onRowClick={this.props.onRowClick} key={row[0]["value"]} row={row}></TableRow>;
    });
}

render(){
    if(this.state.rows && this.state.header){
        return(
            <div>
                {typeof this.props.count === "number" && "Returned " + this.props.count + " records."}
                <table className="table table-striped">
                    <TableHeader updateFilter={this.getFilter} key="header" header={this.state.header}></TableHeader>
                    {this.getRows()}
                </table>
                <Paginator 
                    page={this.state.page} 
                    count={this.props.count} 
                    changePage={this.props.changePage} 
                    perPage={this.state.perPage}
                    offset={this.props.offset}
                ></Paginator>
            </div>
        );
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

Edit: asked to include more code. Sorry for mess

Comment: Can you include the code where `this.state.rows` is updated?

Comment: Can you please try replicating above issue in https://codesandbox.io. It will help us to resolve it faster.